# interpretation of regression result ratio related to y-hat

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

in a multivariate regression one can obtain the so called y-hat $$\hat Y$$ I am trying to understand the interpretation of the following value

$$\frac{\hat Y ^T Y}{\hat Y^T \hat Y}$$

Comment: it's just projecting $Y$ onto the span of $\hat Y$, i.e. for any vectors $u,v$ one has $$\frac{u^Tv}{v^Tv}u$$ is the projection of $u$ onto the line spanned by $v$

Comment: i understand the numerator,but what does the denominator mean and what does the ratio mean, does the unit make sense? For example, say Y is the return vector i am predicting for N assets, and $\hat Y$ is the predictions I have come up with.

Comment: isn't the project of $u$ onto $v$ $\frac{u^Tv}{v^Tv}v$?

Comment: Yes sorry you are right.